# blur-admin をビルドしたい

Tags: node.js, gulp

https://akveo.github.io/blur-admin/articles/002-installation-guidelines/
これをビルドしたいのですが npm ぐらいしか使ったことがなく
glup を初めて使ったんですがエラーの意味がわからずに困っています

---

インストールガイドラインにある通り

```
git clone https://github.com/akveo/blur-admin.git
cd blur-admin
npm install
```

を実行したところ警告は出るものの一応成功しました

そのあと

`gulp serve:dist`

を実行したところ

`ReferenceError: primordials is not defined`

というエラーになります

このエラーで調べたところ
[gulp v4にバージョンアップした事による仕様変更](https://qiita.com/shun_kominato/items/7c9777341a8045d863c2)
という記事が出てきたのでそれに従って

```
npm install -g n
n 11.15.0
```

を実行してみたところ /user/local に書き込みしようとしてエラーになります

うちのシステムが /user/local に書き込みを行う際権限申請が必要なので
n コマンドでインストールする先を /home 以下にかえたいんですが
`man n` が存在せず
`n --help` にもインストール先のパスを設定するオプションもなさそうに見えます

最終的にやりたいのはこの blur-admin の js と scss を Rails 上で動かしたいと思ってるんですが
ビルドの方向性としては nodejs のバージョンを下げるのであってるんでしょうか

本当に必要なのであれば /user/local に書き込み権限を申請しようと思ってますが
手続きが面倒なので他に解決方法があれば教えていただけると助かります

---

環境は

MacOS

node v15.14.0

gulp
CLI version: 2.3.0
Local version: 3.9.1

です

---

追記：

回答でいただいた通り -g なしでインストールしましたがかわりませんでした

```
> npm install n
added 1 package, removed 4 packages, changed 4 packages, and audited 1085 packages in 9s

> which n
/Users/xxxxx/.nodebrew/current/bin/n

> n 11.15.0
  installing : node-v11.15.0
       mkdir : /usr/local/n/versions/node/11.15.0
mkdir: /usr/local/n/versions/node/11.15.0: Permission denied
```

Comment: https://github.com/tj/n#installation を見ますと、環境変数 `N_PREFIX` を指定する様です。例えば `N_PREFIX=$HOME/.n n 11.15.0`

Comment: できました！　ありがとうございます！

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> /Users/xxxxx/.nodebrew/current/bin/n

nodebrew を使ってるなら n を使わなくても

```
nodebrew install v11.15.0
nodebrew user v11.15.0
```

で複数の nodejs バージョンの切り替えはできると思います

ただ

> gulp
> CLI version: 2.3.0
> Local version: 3.9.1

だとすると

> gulp v4にバージョンアップした事による仕様変更

にあてはまらないので複数の nodejs(npm), gulp が入っていてビルド時にみているものが違う可能性があります

Comment: 確かに元から gulp は 3.9 なんですが node のバージョンを下げたら動きました

Answer (score 0):

`npm install -g` の `-g` がグローバルを指しており、これで `/usr/local` 以下などにインストールを試みていると思われます。
このオプションを使わなければローカルインストールになり、コマンドを実行したフォルダ以下にインストールできるのではないでしょうか。